# How to protect myself from parameter misplacement

Tags: java

Let's say i have this important method:

```
int generateId(int clientCode, int dataVersion) {
    return clientCode * 2 + dataVersion % 2;
}
```

Both parameters are `int`, so it's pretty easy to invoke this method with misplaced parameters, like `generateId(dataVersion, clientCode)`. It will be successfully compiled and executed. But generated id will be completely wrong, which can cause severe problems.

So, my question is: is there a way to protect myself from such parameter misplacement?

For now I could only think of changing it to `int` wrapper classes like:

```
int generateId(@Nonnull ClientCode clientCode, @Nonnull Version version) {
    return clientCode.getValue() * 2 + version.getValue() % 2;
}

static class IntWrapper<T> {
    private final int value;

    IntWrapper(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

static class ClientCode extends IntWrapper<ClientCode> {
    ClientCode(int value) {
        super(value);
    }
}

static class Version extends IntWrapper<Version> {
    Version(int value) {
        super(value);
    }
}
```

and invoking it with `generateId(new ClientCode(clientCode), new Version(version))`. Of course, it doesn't guarantee full protection, but at least it's more transparent this way.

Is there any better / other way?

Comment: There are two ways: think about what you're doing and the second one: let your IDE display the parameter names for each method call.

Comment: @Tom, thanks! But I'm not the only one who will use this method. And i can't force everyone to configure their IDE or to `write without bugs`.

Comment: You can't force people to think then they call a method? That's unfortunate.  That's not even complicated like "write without bugs".

Comment: force one to be a string and parse it...check it before parsing

Comment: "it's pretty easy to invoke this method with misplaced parameters". Well, technically it's very easy yes. However, is it a real issue? What if you have two methods that take 2 `int` parameters and you accidentally call the wrong method? That would also compile correctly and yet it would be a bug. There's no named parameters or other similar functionality in Java, so if you're trying to work around this it'll only result in extra work for very little in return. Writing good tests can protect you from this issue.

Comment: @Kayaman, it's a trade-off between code "elegancy" and business risks. If mismatching costs $1M, you can sacrifice "elegancy" in favour of software stability.

Comment: @Jimilian If you can misplace parameters in this method, you can also misplace them with a builder or wrapper, nothing changes.

Comment: @Jimilian certainly. That's why if mismatching costs $1M you won't hire developers who get confused with parameters. You also make sure that your test suites have a huge coverage. You make sure that your parameters are strongly typed and verified (this doesn't protect against the described parameter blindness though). It depends entirely on the situation you're in. If this is the kind of bug you're worried about, then there are most likely a lot more serious bugs that you wouldn't even understand are in the code.

Comment: @grape_mao, it's about API design. You have two options - design self-explained code or design code that needs a lot of documentation (or even reverse engineering).

Comment: @Kayaman, I see your point. If I'm dumb - nothing can help. But, please, give me a try to understand code without reading the underneath implementation.

Comment: @Jimilian I don't see any place where I advocate bad or unclear design, on the contrary. But if you have to baby-proof your code, then maybe you should just fire the developers. If you confuse `clientCode` and `dataVersion` parameters, then you probably shouldn't be allowed to touch the code at all.

Comment: @Kayaman, i agree. However, 2 points. First, everybody make mistakes, even guru developers with decades of experience, we're all human. And second, I don't want to baby-proof all my code this way. Only this specific important method, where it's very easy to make a mistake and very hard to recover from this mistake.

Comment: @esin88 well the fluent builder approach given in the answer is very useful in this case (too), but your example is really poor in depicting a serious issue. An experienced developer would not confuse 2 distinctly named variables unless he's dyslexic. If he does, he really isn't that experienced.

Comment: I agree with Kayaman and even if that developer confuses these parameters, he should get some failed unit tests then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider to configure your Object via Method-Chaining like so

```
configure().withDataVersion(dataVersion).withClientCode(clientCode).generateId();
```

While it makes the configuration far more verbose it is also clearer to read.

The *DataVersion* and *ClientCode*-Information could be moved into an inner class. `configure()` initiates the inner class, the `withDataVersion(int)` and `withClientCode(int)`are basically setters. The `generateId()` will build and return your Id like it does today.

Comment: Wow! Didn't think about this way. Indeed, it's much clearer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Writing wrapper classes for every single parameter, just to ensure that someone doesn't make confusion about the order of parameters sounds pretty extreme, and it is cumbersome to use.

If `clientCode` or `dataVersion` can fit into smaller datatypes such as `byte` or `short`, you can use that for distinction. If some of these values have a specified value range (e.g. from 1 to 100.000), use a compile-time check within a method and throw an exception if the supplied value doesn't fit (which can happen in case when the caller misplaced parameters).

In case that you add more `int` parameters, your concern becomes more justified. In that case write only a single wrapper class that will hold all parameters:

```
public class Input {
    private int clientCode;
    private int version;
    //other parameters
    ..
    // getters and setters
}
```

By using explicit getters and setters, you are forcing caller to take care about the supplied values. Bonus - you can add default values to some of the parameters, if needed. Method signature is now `int generateId(Input input)`.

This is a good practice documented in Joshua Bloch's [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134685997).

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by [Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3824919/tom) in comments java provides no means to avoid this kind of problem. Other languages like python and scala support named arguments to address this.
While this is *good to have* it is not necessary.

Java relies on programmers to properly understand and use all libraries. For this reason proper doc comments should be used and documentation should be generated.

The other alternative of using wrapper classes that you suggested is will make the code cumbersome and difficult to understand. Not to mention add additional lines of code which have no that purpose.

**conclusion**: Rely on programmers knowledge, and generate documentation. Do not use wrapper classes. As this is the widely used approach to this in java community.

Comment: Though OP's problem can be completely solved with Builder pattern. Other scenarios cannot really be solved. You'd have to use code generation to remove the risk completely. Or you can use better tooling to help reduce the risk e.g parameter hints in IntelliJ and Lilit (https://lilit.dev/blog/misplaced)

Answer (score 0):

You on a right way, refactor you code further, make high-grade `ClientCode, Version` and `Id` classes.Remove int wrappers. Make `Id` knows all about how to generate version in other words incapsulate code in `Id` class.

```
Id generateId(ClientCode code, Version version) {
    return new Id(code, version);
}
```

Comment: Wrap all int into Object, so no one would like to use your API, thus no bug. (just kidding...)

Comment: @grape_mao not to simple Objects but to Entities, what is int? it is naked data knows nothing about it mission.